How is it safe mariadb user password?
I have a Java application that uses mariadb password. I would like to be sure any malicious user with access to the filesystem would not have access to the database.
I was wondering how is safe the authentication of mariadb if an user has access to the file system.
Is it not enough to change mysql table files with an known authentication data?
Does exist any safe way to secure mariadb table when user have access to fs?

Do not ever give any malicious user unfettered access to your file system. It's not only the MariaDB user password that is at risk if you do.

I have to develop a distributed fiscal system that should pass an homologation that ensures the data may not be altered by the user (even the pc admin). I'm trying to understand if a relationship database like mariadb is usable

OK, I may have overreacted a bit.  It sounds like the Java application runs on the PC of the user and contains the MySQL password for direct access to the database. Right? Is MySQL installed on the same PC, or on a central server?

Yes your right, it is a standalone offline installation .

access to fs as an admin or a restricted user?  and does the potential attacker also have command line access?

access as admin with cmd line too

Look for "encryption at rest" for a partial answer.

There is no way to protect data on a PC from the admin of that PC. The admin by definition has access to everything.
Even if the MariaDB passwords were 100% secure, the PC admin can run MariaDB with no password enforcement. This isn't even difficult; it's in the documentation as a means to recover access if you forget the password. See https://mariadb.com/docs/server/ref/mdb/system-variables/skip_grant_tables/ or https://www.delftstack.com/howto/mysql/mysql-skip-grant-tables/
If you must protect the data even from admin users, the only way you can do that is not to put the data on the PC. Keep the data on a server you administer (and where they have no access), and give limited access to users via a web API.

Thank you for your answer, but I don't agree with the very first part. As admin I'm not able to decryp an os encrypted volume, I cannot manipulate the antivirus database or installation, I'm not able to access tpm modules and keys.

Unfortunately I'm working on a standalone application that may work offline, a remote server access is not an option.
